# Add 10 to 40 minutes randomly to a datetime column in pandas

Tags: pandas, datetime, group-by, timedelta

I have a data frame as shown below

```
start                      
2010-01-06 09:00:00
2018-01-07 08:00:00
2012-01-08 11:00:00
2016-01-07 08:00:00
2010-02-06 14:00:00
2018-01-07 16:00:00
```

To the above df, I would like to add a column called 'finish' by adding minutes between 10 to 40  with start column randomly with replacement.

Expected Ouput:

```
start                       finish
2010-01-06 09:00:00      2010-01-06 09:20:00
2018-01-07 08:00:00      2018-01-07 08:12:00
2012-01-08 11:00:00      2012-01-08 11:38:00
2016-01-07 08:00:00      2016-01-07 08:15:00
2010-02-06 14:00:00      2010-02-06 14:24:00
2018-01-07 16:00:00      2018-01-07 16:36:00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and [`numpy.random.randint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) for integers between `10` and `40`:

```
arr = np.random.randint(10, 40, size=len(df))
df['finish'] = df['start'] + pd.to_timedelta(arr, unit='Min')
print (df)
                start              finish
0 2010-01-06 09:00:00 2010-01-06 09:25:00
1 2018-01-07 08:00:00 2018-01-07 08:30:00
2 2012-01-08 11:00:00 2012-01-08 11:29:00
3 2016-01-07 08:00:00 2016-01-07 08:12:00
4 2010-02-06 14:00:00 2010-02-06 14:31:00
5 2018-01-07 16:00:00 2018-01-07 16:39:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using [`pandas.Series.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) in combination with [`pandas.to_timedelta()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and [`random.randint()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint).

```
from random import randint
df['finish'] = df.start.apply(lambda dt: dt + pd.to_timedelta(randint(10, 40), unit='m'))
```